# Setting a try / timeout with ftplib in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftplib

How can I set a timeout of 10~ seconds and if it fails to upload or times out to try again?

Current code:

```
print "Uploading LIST{}.html".format(counter)
ftp_session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.website.com','admin@website.com','password123')
rss_ftp_file = open('OUTPUT/LISTS/LIST{}.html'.format(counter),'r')
ftp_session.cwd("/LISTS/")
ftp_session.storlines('STOR LIST{}.html.tmp'.format(counter), rss_ftp_file)
rss_ftp_file.close()
ftp_session.rename('LIST{}.html.tmp'.format(counter), 'LIST{}.html'.format(counter))
ftp_session.quit()
```

Tried the following

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        print "Uploading LIST{}.html".format(counter)
        ftp_session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.website.com','admin@website.com','password123','',60)
        rss_ftp_file = open('OUTPUT/LISTS/LIST{}.html'.format(counter),'r')
        ftp_session.cwd("/LISTS/")
        ftp_session.storlines('STOR LIST{}.html.tmp'.format(counter), rss_ftp_file)
        rss_ftp_file.close()
        ftp_session.rename('LIST{}.html.tmp'.format(counter), 'LIST{}.html'.format(counter))
        ftp_session.quit()
        break
    except:
        continue
else:
    open('OUTPUT/LISTS/LIST{}.html'.format(counter),'w').close()
```

But it uploads each list 3 times, it should upload the list and if it timesout then it should try again but if it timesout 3 times it should delete the content from the listfile as shown in the else. If it successfully uploads it shouldn't try again and it shouldn't pass the else statement

Thanks
- Hyflex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a `timeout` parameter in the `FTP` constructor (as long as you're running 2.6+).

> `class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])`
>
> Return a new instance of the `FTP` class. When `host` is given, the method call `connect(host)` is made. When `user` is given, additionally the method call `login(user, passwd, acct)` is made (where `passwd` and `acct` default to the empty string when not given). The optional `timeout` parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if is not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used).

I believe subsequent blocking operations that take longer than your `timeout` will raise `socket.timeout` exception.  You can catch those and retry as needed.