# What is the default python ftplib timeout on blocking operations?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, ftp

What is the default when setting a timeout for Python 2.7's ftplib? Are there other limits (like sockets) that need to also be set?

The docs mention that if no timeout is provided then the global default is used, but I can't find what the global default actually is.

> `class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])`
>
> Return a new instance of the `FTP` class. When `host` is given, the method call `connect(host)` is made. When `user` is given, additionally the method call `login(user, passwd, acct)` is made (where `passwd` and `acct` default to the empty string when not given). The optional `timeout` parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if is not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used).

There are other questions that ask about setting the default (like [Setting a try / timeout with ftplib in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436922/setting-a-try-timeout-with-ftplib-in-python)), but they don't describe the defaults. Some forum posts talk about that setting not working because sockets or other libraries potentially cutting the connection (like [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/88z_a8Wr7_I)).

What is the default and are there other systems that need to be limits set?

Comment: Don't know in python but default for ftp is 300s

Comment: Adam did you find the value of ftp socket? I also want to know the value of "GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT".

Comment: @wasqas No, thought it seemed like we saw our connection cut at 300s as Bhargav mentions. Whether that is due to the ftplib or is the protocol itself (or maybe even something on the transport layer) I don't know.